# Converting handwritten number to text

Tags: excel, ocr

I need to convert a pdf form that contains a column of handwritten numbers to text and populate an excel spreadsheet.

Does anyone know of a program or a solution to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have tried programs like pdfcompressor, but its returning me random symbols. Im assuming numbers should be easier to convert than random letters.

Comment: You would need something designed specifically for converting handwritten text, most OCR software is setup to read printed text.  Maybe find something designed for a tablet or handheld computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Microsoft Office from XP to 2007, you can use Microsoft Office Document Imaging.  It is a PDF viewer-like program.  Once you open your image file, you can use your mouse icon to crop and highlight sections of the image.  You can then copy and paste the highlighted section into Excel using the built-in OCR software.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need an OCR program (google OCR) to interpret the handwritten text/numbers. But that would then only give you a raw text or .doc file, not an excel sheet. You'd need to manually move the numbers across - might still be better than keying them in, if you're looking at a very large list.

Comment: Even generating raw number in a text file is good. But so far I havent had much success with any of the programs I've downloaded. I'm still trying the PdfCompressor program. Do you know of any other programs?

Answer (score 0):

Abbyy Finereader would be the first place to start. It has support for machine printed and hand printed OCR and comes with a nice GUI interface. You should be able to download a trial version from www.abbyy.com. It will be able to export to all sorts of formats. If you need an SDK then Kadmos from www.rerecognition.com supports hand and machine print OCR.